# Issue while assigning a value to JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, firefox, object

I'm trying following in Firefox 5.0:

```
var db;
var request = mozIndexedDB.open("MyTestDatabase");
request.onerror = function(event) {
  alert("Why didn't you allow my web app to use IndexedDB?!");
};
request.onsuccess = function(event) {
  db = request.result;
  //db = event.target.result; //also tried this
  console.log(db); //get the object
};

console.log(db); //undefined
```

I want db, accessible outside the handler. What is the issue here?
I am trying to learn something from [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB).

There must be a simple thing that I am missing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `db` variable is assigned a value inside the success handler:

```
request.onsuccess = function(event) {
  db = request.result;
  //db = event.target.result; //also tried this
  console.log(db); //get the object
};
```

That handler will be called asynchronously and, in particular, it hasn't been called when you do this:

```
console.log(db); //undefined
```

so you end up with the initial value of `db` that you get from `var db;`.

So, you can access `db` outside the callback but it won't necessarily have a useful value when you want it to. The usual approach is to put calls to things that need `db` inside the success handler. If you need to use `db` elsewhere, you'll have to check that is is defined before you use it and wait if it isn't.

If you need to wait for `db` to be ready before continuing with your application then something like this should work:

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    if(!db) // Not ready yet.
        return;
    // We have a db so we can stop waiting
    clearInterval(timer);
    // and get on with our real work.
    start_main_application();
}, 100);
```

The [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) will trigger every 0.1s and check if there is a `db` yet; if it isn't then it does nothing until the next time the interval is triggered; if there is a `db`, then it [shuts down the timer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval) and starts the main application.

Comment: How to check if handler executed the function?

Comment: can we make a wait loop to for further execution?

Comment: We may not need timer function if I call start_main_application() function from handler itself.

Comment: Can't I make a synchronous call?

Comment: I got sync call API reference [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#opening-sync)

Comment: Foolish search, Implemented api is there in https://developer.mozilla.org/en/indexeddb Both sync and async apis are there.... :-) but sync api is not implemented yet :-(

Comment: @Vikas: Doing the `start_main_application` from the callback would make the most sense. Unless you had a couple async things to wait for of course.

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(db); //undefined
```

Sure, it is undefined there, it is right behavior.

See, what is happening: you are doing the request, and submitting a handler that handles that request (onsuccess). The initialization is happening in handler body, but event has not yet happen! The codeflow goes to console.log(db); line, but db is not intialized there, because handler has not been called yet.

As soon as onsuccess happens, handler is called and db intialized. Only after that you can use that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that request will not set the result variable itself (i.e. request.result).

The parameters in function(event) might have the 'result' value.